# How to solve error "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"?

Tags: r, for-loop

I was trying to execute this functions, but I kept on getting an error with my if statment:

> Error in if (unique(AGE$age[AGE$age[i]] > 60)) { : missing value where
>   TRUE/FALSE needed

```
y<-NULL
for(i in unique(infofile$family)){
  AGE<-infofile[infofile$family==i,]
  if(unique(AGE$age[i]> 60)){
    AGE$yearsold[i]<-"OLD"
  }else{AGE$yearsold[i]<-"YOUNG"}
  y<-rbind(y,AGE)
}
```

Comment: Try unique(AGE$age[i])> 60 instead

Comment: Probably there is `na` value for `AGE$age` or  `unique(AGE$age[i]> 60` condition doesn't match any row.

Comment: I just tried your advise, but I still can not solve the problem.

Comment: Please update your question by posting reproducible errors (sample data), so that it anyone can easily respond. Thanks

Comment: I have used is.na(unique(AGE$age[i]) to check, but there is not any NA.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is to create a new column based on the condition on  `age`  then you can do it without using a  `for`  loop. Try the code below:

```
AGE$yearsold <- ifelse(AGE$age>60, "OLD", "YOUNG")
```

Comment: Thank you. But my teacher asked me to use for loop to solve this problem.LOL

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see, I think what you want is:

```
sum(AGE$age<=60, na.rm = TRUE) < 1
```

If TRUE then is like 1 and if FALSE is like 0

Comment: Thank you. I ran this code and it is TRUE, so what should I do next?

Comment: I think if you replace unique(AGE$age[i]> 60) by sum(AGE$age[i]<=60) < 1 it will work, is there a new error?

Comment: It seems doesn't work. I still got the error message.

Comment: mmm I have edited to remove nans... can you print AGE$age[i] before arribing to the if condition?

Comment: I think the problem maybe is: When I type                                  
    AGE$age[i]>60                                                                                  , what I got is NA, not TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: sum(AGE$age<=60, na.rm = TRUE) < 1 , try this

Comment: I got new error message: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "yearsold", value = c(NA, NA, "OLD" : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 2

Comment: AGE$yearsold<-"YOUNG"

Comment: oh, it works!!!                                                                                                            Thank you very much! Can you explain for me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: your var i is an index, you already filter AGE by this index, so you don't need to do it again, in fact by filtering it returns na since it is out of index

Comment: You are so nice.                                                                                   
 May I ask why you replace sum unique(AGE$age[i]> 60 by (AGE$age<=60, na.rm = TRUE) < 1 ?